# how to use .query attribute in sqlacodegen models

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

When I use sqlacodegen to create models.py I can't use `User.query`, getting the warning "[AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'query']".
I think db.query is a very usable attribute, it's used in SQLAlchemy():

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

But I need to use sqlacodegen to create models for existing table in our system. Creation code below:

models.py

```
# coding: utf-8
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, Float, Integer, String, Table, text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = u'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(64))
    username = Column(String(64))
    role_id = Column(Integer)
    password_hash = Column(String(128))
```

Now I import models.py:

```
from models import *
@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.name.data).first()
...
```

When I run this, the warning given is:

```
AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'query'
```

I want to know how I can trans [class User(Base)] to a type like [class User(db.Model)] so it can use .query attribute? Or is there some other usable method to do that with [class User(Base) ]type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you're used to using Flask-SQLAlchemy, which includes the secret sauce to allow the functionality you mention.

The [Flask Docs on SQLAlchemy](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/sqlalchemy/#declarative) indicate how to get that same functionality:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////tmp/test.db', convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                     autoflush=False,
                                     bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()
```

It'll enable the shorthand of `User.query....` that you expect.  The important line is the last one.  You could alternatively use the `db.Model` class from Flask-SQLAlchemy instead of the 'pure' SQLAlchemy `Base` class.